# Higher order component always rerenders ignoring shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I have a higher order component like this

```
// higherOrderComponent.js
const HigherOrderComponent = Component => class extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return false
  }

  render () {
    return <Component {...this.props} />
  }
}

export default HigherOrderComponent

// myComponent.js
import HigherOrderComponent from './higherOrderComponent'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>my component</div>
  }
}

export default HigherOrderComponent(MyComponent)

// parentComponent.js
import MyComponent from './myComponent'

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <MyComponent />
  }
}
```

I explicitly return false but the component always get re-rendered. Any idea why? I ultimately want to share the "shouldComponentUpdate" across components. How can I achieve that if higher order component does not work?

Comment: always get re-rendered when?

Comment: Hello, I wrote some code based on your component and found indeed you are correct. Let me see how can we fix this.

Answer (score 1):

since you have not specified how you are invoking your Higher Order component, based on the issue I have made a guess how you might be using it.

My Answer is based on the assumption that you are invoking your higher order function like

```
var MyHigherOrderFn = (HigherOrderComponent(Baar));
```

If Some you how you can invoke your higher order function like  below into `return` in `render`, you can avoid the issue.

```
<HigherOrderComponent prop1="Hello" child="Child" />
```

Since I don;t know how invoke your function in above way(I am not sure its even possible), I have created `HigherOrderComponent2` with different syntax style which can be invoked like, which in turn comply with `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
<Parent prop1="val1">
    <Child>
</Parent>
```

---

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';


/*This is simeple child component*/
class Baar extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.name}</div>);
  }
}


/*This is your higher order component*/
const HigherOrderComponent = Component => class extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
  }

  render () {
    return <Component {...this.props} />
  }
}

/*This is another way to write higher order component*/
class HigherOrderComponent2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
  }

  render(){

    let child = this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children,
        {...this.props}
    );

    return <div>{child}</div>
  }
}



/*Problem that you are facing how you invoke your Higher Order Compoent*/
export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onHandleClick = this.onHandleClick.bind(this);
    this.state={
      name: 'Praveen Prasad'
    }
  }

  onHandleClick(){
    this.setState({
      name:Math.random()
    });
  }

  render() {
    {'This is how you might be invoking you higher order component, at this time react render doesnt know it already exists in DOM or not'}
    {'this component will always re-render, irrespective of values in shouldComponentUpdate'}
    var Baaz = (HigherOrderComponent(Baar));
    return (<div>
      <button onClick={this.onHandleClick}>Update Name</button>
        <Baaz name={this.state.name} />

        {'This is  another way to invoke higher order Component , and this will respect shouldComponentUpdate'}
        <HigherOrderComponent2 name={this.state.name}>
          <Baar />
        </HigherOrderComponent2>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: I honestly do not want to create another higher order component for a higher order component for it to work.

Comment: I am not saying to create another HOF but I am saying how you are consuming it.

Comment: Problem in your code is how you might be consuming it.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to create a snippet and it works as intended, `MyComponent.render` is called only once when `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`.

My guess is that somehow you are using the unwrapped version of MyComponent instead of the wrapped one. Maybe a problem with your build environment?

```js
// higherOrderComponent.js
const HigherOrderComponent = Component => class extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
  }

  render () {
    return <Component {...this.props} />
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
   console.log('render');
    return <div>my component</div>
  }
}

const MyComponentHOC = HigherOrderComponent(MyComponent);

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <MyComponentHOC />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent/>, document.getElementById('container'));
ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about the life cycle for a react component. When a component get initialized, it will not check shouldComponentUpdate. ShouldComponentUpdate will only be called when state/props CHANGED.

FYI the lifecycle methods call in order:

**When a component is initialized:**
getDefaultProps
getInitialStage
componentWillMount
render
componentDidMount

**When a component has state changed:**
shouldComponentUpdate
componentWillUpdate
render
componentDidUpdate

**When a component has props changed:**
componentWillReceiveProps
shouldComponentUpdate
componentWillUpdate
render
componentDidUpdate

**When a component is unmounting:**
componentWillUnmount

Comment: That is not true. According the the docs here, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate "If shouldComponentUpdate returns false, then render() will be completely skipped until the next state change"

Comment: @manni The doc says "Invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate is used." When the component is initialized, the shouldComponentUpdate is not used for checking before rendering.

Comment: @manni I have created a sample. https://jsfiddle.net/viviancpy/3228rctx/1/ You could open up Chrome console (F12) and observe the log printed. There is nothing printed for ShouldComponentUpdate in the component initialization phrase.

Comment: i am neither using forceUpdate or talking about initial render. It is ignoring shouldComponentUpdate when props change.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a different type of `HOC` pattern called inheritance inversion to access the lifecycle methods. Since you are overriding `shouldComponentUpdate` you don't call `super` however it is required to call `super.render()` inside the subclassed components render method.

Try this...

```
const HigherOrderComponent = () => WrappedComponent =>
  class ShouldNotUpdate extends WrappedComponent {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return false
    }
    render() {
      return super.render()
    }
  }
```

it's good practice to use currying so as you could annotate your classes in the future like...

```
@HigherOrderComponent
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>something</div>
  }
}

// or without annotations..

const MyNewClass = HigherOrderComponent()(MyClass)
```